# Sub divide a dictionary into smaller parts

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am trying to sub divide a dictionary into smaller parts. My approach works, I am just wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it. For the sake of the example, the dictionary has 10 elements but my code can have up to 1000 and would be in batches of 50 to which I am passing to an api.

My Questain is there a more efficient way of doing this...?

```
int divideamount = 2;

Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("cat1", "cat");
dictionary.Add("dog2", "cat");
dictionary.Add("cat3", "cat");
dictionary.Add("dog4", "cat");
dictionary.Add("cat5", "cat");
dictionary.Add("dog6", "cat");
dictionary.Add("cat7", "cat");
dictionary.Add("dog8", "cat");
dictionary.Add("cat9", "cat");
dictionary.Add("dog10", "cat");


var divided_dictionary
    = dictionary.Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Index / divideamount)
                .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value))
                .ToList();


foreach (Dictionary<string, string> division in divided_dictionary)
{ 
    // do some work
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Partition` method from moreLINQ library](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Partition.cs).

```
var divided_dictionary
    = dictionary.Partition(divideamount)
                .Select(x => x.ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value));
```

I wrote a blog post about partitioning collections using LINQ a while ago. You may find it useful: [Partitioning the collection using LINQ: different approaches, different performance, the same result](http://marcinjuraszek.com/2013/12/partitioning-the-collection-using-linq-different-approaches-different-performance-the-same-result.html).

Comment: Extremely well written and helpful. Thanks for your help its greatly appreciated. I will try that now.

Comment: The syntax in this example does not appear to work any longer.